# PHP, find element of XML and do something with it

Tags: php, xml

I've got the following problem, I've got an import.xml with an example content like

```
<abc></abc>
<lable_def name="Label" x="100" y="200" z="300"></label_def>
<abcd></abcd>
....
...
```

Now I want the following:

```
if the tag is = <lable_def name"Label" 
than delete X and Y Tags
and value of Z minus 6
and add the tag haschanged="1"
```

The whole XML should be saved as new.xml with alle the original content but withe changed things, like:

```
<abc></abc>
<lable_def name="Label" z="294" haschanged="1"></label_def>
<abcd></abcd>
....
...
```

How do I solve this with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using one of the XML APIs like DOM. Xpath expressions allow you to fetch parts of a DOM.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<foo>
<abc></abc>
<label_def name="Label" x="100" y="200" z="300"></label_def>
<abcd></abcd>
</foo>
XML;

// bootstrap the DOM document
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// find any element "label_def" with the "name" attribute "Label"
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//label_def[@name="Label"]') as $label) {
   // remove x and y attributes
   $label->removeAttribute('x');
   $label->removeAttribute('y');
   // decrease z attribute
   $label->setAttribute('z', $label->getAttribute('z') - 6);
   // add haschanged attribute 
   $label->setAttribute('haschanged', '1');
}

echo $document->saveXML();
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo>
<abc/>
<label_def name="Label" z="294" haschanged="1"/>
<abcd/>
</foo>
```